# Adding font to Dart Command Line Application

Tags: dart

I'm trying to generate a PDF file from a source based on conditions. The data I'm dealing with is written in Turkish. That's why, there are font errors. I need to use a font that supports Turkish characters but I'm not able to use it in Dart Command Line Application.

That's why I wonder is there a way to import font files to Dart Application? Or is there another way to solve unicode encoder convert error?

I'm using [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) library to generate pdf files.

```
#0      _UnicodeSubsetEncoder.convert (dart:convert/ascii.dart:89:9)
#1      Latin1Codec.encode (dart:convert/latin1.dart:40:46)
#2      PdfFont.stringMetrics
package:pdf/…/pdf/font.dart:174
#3      RichText.layout.<anonymous closure>
package:pdf/…/widgets/text.dart:607
#4      TextSpan.visitChildren
package:pdf/…/widgets/text.dart:436
#5      RichText.layout
package:pdf/…/widgets/text.dart:583
#6      Align.layout
package:pdf/…/widgets/basic.dart:313
#7      Flex.layout
package:pdf/…/widgets/flex.dart:294
#8      Page.layout
package:pdf/…/widgets/page.dart:200
#9      Page.postProcess
package:pdf/…/widgets/page.dart:142
#10     Document.save
package:pdf/…/widgets/document.dart:118
#11     gethtml
bin/vvitru.dart:93
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     main
bin/vvitru.dart:14
#13     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there is no need to import font inside pubspec.yaml. Just pasting directory of font file is enough to use it.

Like that:

```
  final fontData =
      File('/Users/zahidtekbas/Downloads/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')
          .readAsBytesSync();
  final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(fontData.buffer.asByteData());
```